# JQuery Show function spoiling page style in Chrome and Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, safari

I will try to explain what is going on..
I have an extra div which I show if the appropriate select option was selected.
In Firefox works perfectly, but in Chrome or Safari when the extra div is shown, the footer stays where it was before (it is not at the bottom but in the middle of the page when the extra div is showed)

I think there is some webkit to add..

Here is an example, try to open it in Safari or Firefox. It should work different if the window of the output is small.

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/al_kinkopf/v4po4gwc/7/)

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        /* Safari */
        -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        /* Safari 6.1+ */
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    .content {
        background-color: #f7f7f7;
        clear: both;
        min-height: 250px;
        padding: 20px 10%;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#extra_div").hide();
    });


    $('.selectpicker').change(function () {

        if ($(this).val() == '3') {
            $("#extra_div").show();
        } else {
            $("#extra_div").hide();
        }


    })
</script>

<body>
    <div id="okvir_registracije" style="background-color: #f7f7f7;margin-top: 73px; -webkit-flex: 1; -ms-flex: 1; flex: 1;">
        </br>
        <div class="content" id="login_content">
            <form name="registration" class="registration" method="post" id="form_login" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
                <fieldset style="background: white">
                    <label style="margin-left: 10px">Choose one:</label>
                    <select class="selectpicker" name="tip_uporabnika" id="tip_uporabnika" for="tip_uporabnika" onchange="show_div()">
                        <option value="1" selected="selected">izberi tip uporabnika</option>
                        <option value="3">Uporabnik</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="extra_div">
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Test 2</label>
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px">Test</label>
                        <select class="selectpicker" name="tip_uporabnika" id="tip_uporabnika" for="tip_uporabnika" onchange="show_div()">
                            <option value="1" selected="selected">izberi tip uporabnika</option>
                            <option value="2">Uporabnik</option>
                            <option value="3">Lastnik</option>
                        </select>
                        </br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/></br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/></br>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="ime">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="vaše ime...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="priimek">Surname</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="vaš priimek...">
                        <br/>
                        <label style="margin-left: 10px" for="username">Example</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="vaše uporabniško ime...">
                        <br/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="footer" style="padding: 15px 0;text-align: center;width: 100%;height:25px;">&copy; Company | info@company.si</div>
</body>
```

I hope that is enough to find out what is causing the strange behaviour. As I said it works OK in Firefox, but not in Chrome and Safari.

Here is an image of how it looks in Safari:

[image]

Comment: Anything? What should I start to looking for to find a solution?

Comment: You're going to need to post your code.

Comment: Yes I have some troubles with posting Fiddle link..now it should be ok.